# Reduce/Solve an equation with symbols in powers

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic

I am trying to solve the following equation with respect to `x`.

```
eqn = x^z + y == a;
```

But when I do

```
Reduce[eqn,x]
```

mathematica doesn't solve at all. I guess this is because of symbolic expression in powers. If I replace `z` into some numeric values, mathematica works immediately.

I was wondering what I am missing with this.

Comment: Try adding `Reals` as the domain in `Reduce`.

Comment: What I want to get is general expression
x=(a-y)^(1/z)

Comment: That solution is only correct under certain conditions.  `Reduce` generates these conditions automatically when it can.  Alternatively, you can tell `Reduce` about your variables a little bit: are they real?  positive? etc.

Comment: Is there any other function that could yield
x=(a-y)^(1/z) ???

Comment: Assuming, $x\text{,}y\text{,}z\in\mathbb{R}$ then another acceptable solution is $|x|>0$ when $z=0$ and $y=a-1$. So is $x=0$ and $y=a$ when $z>0$.

Comment: Solve, which is less concerned with being wrong* than Reduce, will in fact give (a-y)^(1/z). *By wrong I do not mean it did something wrong, but simply that the result could be invalid once some actual values are plugged into the parameters. This generally comes about from branch cuts that cannot be computed until parameters receive actual values.

Answer (score 2):

I tested both suggested answers.

```
eqn = x^z + y == a;  
Reduce[eqn, x, Reals]
```

Gives the output:

```
(z > 0 && y == -0^z + a && x == 0) || (y == -1 + a && z == 0 && 
   x < 0) || ((z/2 | C[1]) \[Element] 
    Integers && ((C[1] <= -1 && y < a && z == C[1] && 
       x == -(a - y)^((1/z))) || (C[1] >= 1 && y < a && z == C[1] && 
       x == -(a - y)^((1/z))))) || (((1 + z)/2 | C[1]) \[Element] 
    Integers && 
   y > a && ((C[1] <= -1 && z == C[1] && 
       x == -(-a + y)^((1/z))) || (C[1] >= 1 && z == C[1] && 
       x == -(-a + y)^((1/z))))) || (y == -1 + a && z == 0 && 
   x > 0) || (z != 0 && y < a && x == (a - y)^(1/z))
```

Where as

```
eqn = x^z + y == a;  
Solve[eqn, x]
```

Gives the output:

```
{{x -> (a - y)^(1/z)}}
```

So either method will return the answer you want, though `Solve[]` seems to give the particular format that your looking for.